# Error using ADAL in Android app for Teams

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, microsoft-teams, adal

I have developed a SharePoint WebPart that I'm using in Teams. This WebPart obtains, using ADAL, a token to validate the user.

This application works fine in Sharepoint, Teams (online & desktop app) but when I try to execute this WebPart inside the Android app for Teams I have this error:

I don't know if I need a special certificate in this case...

```
04-28 13:10:13.913  8456  8763 I OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1870ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=187039755963, Vsync=187739755935, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=187755761281, AnimationStart=187755814874, PerformTraversalsStart=187756295135, DrawStart=188864679249, SyncQueued=188871540812, SyncStart=188872232895, IssueDrawCommandsStart=188874670916, SwapBuffers=188907635343, FrameCompleted=188911356593, DequeueBufferDuration=227000, QueueBufferDuration=2864000, 
04-28 13:10:13.935  8456  8456 I PersonalAppsPagerAdapter: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: main, TabID: 14d6962d-6eeb-4f48-8890-de55454bb136 badge count: 0
04-28 13:10:13.959  8456  8456 I PersonalAppsPagerAdapter: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: main, TabID: 20c3440d-c67e-4420-9f80-0e50c39693df badge count: 0
04-28 13:10:13.965  8456  8456 I PersonalAppsPagerAdapter: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: main, TabID: 86fcd49b-61a2-4701-b771-54728cd291fb badge count: 0
04-28 13:10:13.968  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: main, onError
04-28 13:10:13.968  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction: com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationException: Request authority:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common clientid:1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264 No result returned from acquireTokenSilent
04-28 13:10:13.968  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.tryAcquireTokenSilent(AcquireTokenRequest.java:394)
04-28 13:10:13.968  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.performAcquireTokenRequest(AcquireTokenRequest.java:356)
04-28 13:10:13.968  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.access$200(AcquireTokenRequest.java:55)
04-28 13:10:13.968  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest$1.run(AcquireTokenRequest.java:129)
04-28 13:10:13.968  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
04-28 13:10:13.968  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
04-28 13:10:13.968  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
04-28 13:10:13.970  8456  8456 W AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: main, com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationException: Request authority:https://login.microsoftonline.com/
04-28 13:10:13.972  8456  8456 E acquire_resource_token_from_authsdk: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: main, Scenario has already ended for stepId eb376f5c-dddd-yyyy-xxx-112532bc4868 for scenario acquire_resource_token_from_authsdk 
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: main, com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationException: Request authority:https://login.microsoftonline.com/
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction: com.microsoft.skype.teams.services.authorization.AuthorizationError: com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationException: Request authority:https://login.microsoftonline.com/
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.skype.teams.services.authorization.actions.GetResourceTokenAction$4.onError(GetResourceTokenAction.java:322)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.skype.teams.services.authorization.adal.AdalAuthenticationProvider$2.onError(AdalAuthenticationProvider.java:352)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest$CallbackHandler$1.run(AcquireTokenRequest.java:991)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction: Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationException: Request authority:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common clientid:1fec8e78-b222-222f-a22b-514512382264 No result returned from acquireTokenSilent
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.tryAcquireTokenSilent(AcquireTokenRequest.java:394)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.performAcquireTokenRequest(AcquireTokenRequest.java:356)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.access$200(AcquireTokenRequest.java:55)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest$1.run(AcquireTokenRequest.java:129)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
04-28 13:10:13.974  8456  8456 E AuthorizationService_GetResourceTokenAction:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
04-28 13:10:13.998  8456  8456 I MainActivity: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: main, Google Play Services connection is successful.
04-28 13:10:13.999  8456  8456 I Choreographer: Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-28 13:10:14.007  8456  9484 I DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: $Proxy0
04-28 13:10:14.085  8456 11589 E TranslatorMessageUtilities: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: pool-1-thread-44, GetTranslationSupportedLanguages: unsuccessful. Error message:User is not authorized.. Response Code:401
04-28 13:10:14.199  8456  8763 I OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1440ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=187756436031, Vsync=188989769315, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=188997886332, AnimationStart=188998025082, PerformTraversalsStart=189060853832, DrawStart=189182806488, SyncQueued=189187391072, SyncStart=189187852218, IssueDrawCommandsStart=189189284718, SwapBuffers=189194257374, FrameCompleted=189197163728, DequeueBufferDuration=221000, QueueBufferDuration=1885000, 
04-28 13:10:14.275  8456  8456 I com.microsoft.skype.teams.calendar.viewmodels.MeetingsViewModel: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: main, Loading meeting event list. Force refresh: false
04-28 13:10:14.276  8456 11658 D skia    : --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
04-28 13:10:14.280  8456 11658 I chatty  : uid=10136(com.microsoft.teams) FrescoIoBoundEx identical 16 lines
04-28 13:10:14.280  8456 11658 D skia    : --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
04-28 13:10:14.280  8456  9608 I com.microsoft.skype.teams.calendar.viewmodels.MeetingsViewModel: ProcessId: 8456, Thread: Pool-ViewData-Thread-3, setViewState is called with false isError value and 0 item count
```

This is my code:

```
// Obtaining loginName from Sharepoint context
let loginName = this.context.pageContext.user.loginName;
let source = Sources.sharepoint;

// Obtaining loginName from Teams context
if (this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams) {
    loginName = this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.context.loginHint;
    source = Sources.teams;
}

// Obtaining token provider
let tp = await this.context.aadTokenProviderFactory.getTokenProvider();
let config = tp["_defaultConfiguration"];
let aadInstanceUrl = config.aadInstanceUrl[length - 1] === "/" ? config.aadInstanceUrl : config.aadInstanceUrl + "/";

// Config context
let ctx = new AuthenticationContext({
    tenant: tenantId,
    clientId: clientId,
    instance: aadInstanceUrl,
    redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
    extraQueryParameter: "login_hint=" + encodeURIComponent(loginName),
    loadFrameTimeout: 60000
});

// Check user
let cu = ctx.getCachedUser();

console.log("USER", cu, loginName, ctx);
if (cu && cu.userName.toLowerCase() !== loginName.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log("Clean user cache");
    ctx.clearCache();
}

// Login process
console.log("Login process");

// Obtaining Azure AD Token
let azureADToken = this.acquireToken(ctx, clientId);
```

Could somebody give me a clue to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: we are checking this issue.

Comment: ADAL is being phased out on Mobile with [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview).